# Why am I seeing cached data instead of the updated data?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The information that displays after the `DoCmd.OpenTable` is the previous state of the data, not the current state.

```
CurrentDb().QueryDefs.Delete "qry_attributeData"
Set attriQryDef = CurrentDb().CreateQueryDef("qry_attributeData")
sqlStr = Replace(sqlStr, "#catReplace#", replaceVal)
attriQryDef.Connect = cxString1
attriQryDef.SQL = sqlStr
attriQryDef.Close
CurrentDb.Execute "Drop Table [tbl_attributeData]", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT qry_attributeData.* INTO tbl_attributeData FROM qry_attributeData", dbFailOnError
DoCmd.OpenTable "tbl_attributeData"
```

It's showing temporary cached data and then throws the error:

> Not a valid bookmark

I can't seem to find any data anywhere showing this issue.

The reason that I'm going through all this trouble is that I have a varying attributes that change the number of columns.

Comment: basically, I'm using the information to generate a table that will attributes of the item.

Comment: I assume `qry_attributeData` is a query, Mustn't you rerun the query? It is probably the query that caches.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I changed the information to include more of the code.  sorry, first post. :-(

Comment: @HansUp unfortunately, adding `DoEvents` doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DROP` the table and recreate it within a transaction.  Use *dbForceOSFlush* when you commit the transaction, which *"forces the database engine to immediately flush all updates to disk"*.  (See [Workspace.CommitTrans Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835985.aspx))

After that has all completed, `DoCmd.OpenTable` should show you the new data.

```vb
Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
Set wrk = DBEngine(0)
wrk.BeginTrans
CurrentDb.Execute "Drop Table [tbl_attributeData]", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT qry_attributeData.* INTO tbl_attributeData FROM qry_attributeData", dbFailOnError
wrk.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
wrk.Close
DoCmd.OpenTable "tbl_attributeData"
Set wrk = Nothing
```